# vnc viewer error: unable connect to socket: Connection refused (111)

Tags: linux, centos, vnc, vnc-viewer

I installed tigervnc-server package in server.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa tigervnc-server
tigervnc-server-1.1.0-5.el6.i686
```

Created a vnc user and created vncpasswd also for that user.

```
[root@localhost ~]# useradd vnc
[root@localhost ~]# vncpasswd vnc
Password:
Verify:
[root@localhost ~]#
```

In `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver` I changed these 2 lines

```
VNCSERVERS="2:vnc"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -localhost"
```

After that I restarted the `vncserver` service

```
[root@localhost ~]# service vncserver restart
Shutting down VNC server: 2:vnc                            [  OK  ]
Starting VNC server: 2:vnc 
New 'localhost.localdomain:2 (vnc)' desktop is localhost.localdomain:2

Starting applications specified in /home/vnc/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/vnc/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:2.log

                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Cleared `iptables` also.

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -F
```

While running vncviewer in client side I am getting this error

```
[root@client ~]# vncviewer 10.10.2.39:2
```

[image]

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your server is only listening on the loopback address `localhost.localdomain:2`.  Try launching it with the server's IP address specified explicitly:

```
vncserver -interface [address]
```

Comment: Great... I just changed this line `VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -localhost"` to this `VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600"` now it's working fine.

Answer (score 13):

Also you might want to try this option:

```
-localhost no
```

The command that works for me is:

```
vncserver -localhost no -geometry 800x600 -depth 24
```

The idea is to have vncserver listen on the network interface, rather than just the loopback interface (lo).

Comment: the only option which works for 1.7.0 tigervnc server

Comment: This finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down the server with this command
"vncserver -kill :1"
then start the viewer again, no need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this command works for me: `vncserver -interface [address] -localhost no`

Comment: Can you provide a reference ?